# Position in vector based on approximate matching

Tags: r

I have the **sorted** vector

```
m<-c(1.1, 3.2, 3.6, 4, 4.6, 4.6, 5.6, 5.7, 6.2, 8.9)
```

I want to find the position of a value based on approximate matching. If the value does not exist in the vector i would like the position of the immediately previous value

for exact matching I would use

```
> match(4,m)
[1] 4
```

But if I do

```
> match(6,m)
[1] NA
```

What i would like to get in this example is `8` (the position of the immidiately previous value of 6 which is the position of 5.7 which is **8**)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want to find the index for a single value or for several values? If you need several values, see my answer below regarding using `findInterval`.

Comment: I agree, @Tommy's answer  to use `findInterval` is best.

Comment: See also [How to efficiently find the index of a value in a sorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70240851/how-to-efficiently-find-the-index-of-a-value-in-a-sorted-array) for some fast `Rcpp` alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `which.max` in combination with vector subsetting, a solution of 17 characters:

```
which.max(m[m<=6]) # Edited to specify <=
[1] 8
```

Since your vector is sorted, you can use the even shorter:

```
sum(m<=6) # Edited to specify <=
[1] 8
```

This works because the value `TRUE` is implicitly converted to 1 in the `sum`

Comment: @ECII I just noticed a small error.  I think the correct operator is `<=` instead of `<` - otherwise it will not find exact matches.  Please check your own results.

Comment: damn... I had considered sum() but thought it might be obtuse for the questioner...  clarifying why was a good idea. :)  BTW, max(which()) is, surprisingly to some, faster than which.max(y[]) because of the speed of []... it's almost as fast as the sum() solution

Answer (score 11):

There is a built-in function that does precisely what you want: `findInterval`
...It's vectorized as well, so you can give it several values to find in one go which is much more efficient.

```
m <- c(1.1, 3.2, 3.6, 4, 4.6, 4.6, 5.6, 5.7, 6.2, 8.9)
# Find nearest (lower) index for both 4 and 6
findInterval(c(4,6), m) 
# [1] 4 8
```

Comment: +1 Brilliant.  I knew this had to exist, but have never been able to find it.  Thank you.

Comment: @Andrie - Yeah, the naming of R functions isn't always obvious!

Answer (score 3):

This should do it for you.

```
#v is a sorted vector and x is an item for which we want the exact or nearest lower match
lowSideMatch <- function(x, v) max(which(v <= x))

lowSideMatch(6, m)
[1] 8

lowSideMatch(4, m)
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `which()` function to get the index of the element with the smallest deviation from your searched value. Also works with unordered vectors.

```
x <- c(8,4,1,2,3,6,9)
find <- 6
pos <- which(abs(x-find) == min(abs(x-find)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using c++ `upper_bound` with `Rcpp` might be fast.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction(
  "int upper_bound(double v, const Rcpp::NumericVector& x) {
     return std::distance(x.begin(), std::upper_bound(x.begin(), x.end(), v));
}")

upper_bound(4, m)
#[1] 4

upper_bound(6, m)
#[1] 8
```

Benchmark:

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e6
m <- sort(rnorm(n, 0, 2))

bench::mark(which_min = c(which(abs(m-4) == min(abs(m-4))), which(abs(m-6) == min(abs(m-6))))
          , which.max = c(which.max(m[m<=4]), which.max(m[m<=6]))
          , length = c(length(m[m<=4]), length(m[m<=6]))
          , max_which = c(max(which(m <= 4)), max(which(m <= 6)))
          , sum = c(sum(m<=4), sum(m<=6))
          , findIntervall = findInterval(c(4,6), m)
          , CPP_upper_bound = c(upper_bound(4, m), upper_bound(6, m)))
#  expression           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 which_min        16.33ms  18.33ms      51.1        NA     55.0    26    28
#2 which.max         9.38ms  11.46ms      73.1        NA    101.     37    51
#3 length            8.41ms  10.06ms      79.7        NA    112.     40    56
#4 max_which         5.89ms   7.48ms     136.         NA     67.8    68    34
#5 sum               2.68ms   3.33ms     274.         NA     45.9   137    23
#6 findIntervall   679.33µs  788.1µs    1214.         NA      0     607     0
#7 CPP_upper_bound   2.31µs   2.75µs  307024.         NA     30.7 10000     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
> m<-c(1.1, 3.2, 3.6, 4, 4.6, 4.6, 5.6, 5.7, 6.2, 8.9)

> ( index = length(m[m<=4]) )
[1] 4

> ( m[index] )
[1] 4

> ( index = length(m[m<=6]) )
[1] 8

> ( m[index] )
[1] 5.7
```

Comment: `m[index]` is an element of `m`, which isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: Although you do bring up an important point that a vector-based solution is better in R than a loop.  Lemme edit my answer...

Comment: @Jack Maney I added some output to make it more clear. I think that's what the OP wanted, but will withdraw the answer if it's still incorrect (it's early and I have a hangover from hell) :D